# Corrupción de Modulos (node_modules)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, modulos

Tengo un problema con un proyecto que funciona de manera local (en una pc propia), este esta desarrollado en nodejs, y utilizo npm para descargar los modulos necesarios para mi chatbot, este es el package.json de mi proyecto

```
{
  "name": "chatbot-sctr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.18.1",
    "npm": "6.14.5"
  },
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon --ignore *.json app.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ibm-watson": "^5.7.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.27",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6",
    "qrcode-terminal": "^0.12.0",
    "whatsapp-web.js": "^1.11.1"
  }
}
```

El problema es que los modulos de Whatsapp-web.js se corrompen de manera seguida, despues de pasar una semana o ese tiempo mas o menos, lo que tengo que hacer es instalar nuevamente esta dependencia

El problema sucede en PUPPETER que es parte del modulo de Whatsapp-web.js, nose porque se dana o se corrompe

El problema es la limpieza que hace windows? o algo parecido, o hay una manera de proteger estos modulos para que no se corrompan

Adjunto las capturas de pantalla de los errores

[image: npm whatsapp-web.js]

[image: npm whatsapp-web.js 2]

Espero puedan ayudarme

Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que se *corrompen*? ¿Cuáles son los síntomas? ¿Cuáles son los errores?

Comment: ya adjunte los errores que me salen cuando se corrompen los modulos que uso, siempre es con el npm whatsapp-web.js